# React: How to replace a JSX tag within a function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx

I'm trying to modify a child component existing within a function component.

Let's say this is the original `Table` function component I would like to render in my own `CustomizedTable` function component. Since the `Table` function component is beautifully designed, I don't want to modify the entire function or structure. What I hope to achieve is to customize and replace the existing `Body` component

```
const Table = (props) => {
  return (
    <Context props={props}>
      <Container className={props.className} style={props.style}>
          <Header />
          <Body
              ColumnComponents={ColumnData}
              RowComponents={RowData}
          />
          <Footer />
      </Container>
    </Context>
  );
});
```

How do I find and replace the `<Body/>` component with `<CustomizedBody>` that is nested within the `Table` function component? Is there a way to modify it without touching the existing `<Body>`?

```
   import { Table } from './Table';


   const CustomizedBody = (props) => {
   return (
      <Body>
      // Body Add Ons
      </Body>
   )}

   export const CustomizedTable = (props) => { 
    
   return (
       <Table Body={<CustomizedBody>}>
       </Table>
   )}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing it as a `props` you can use it as `props.children` in the main component.

> React recommends using composition pattern over the inheritance. You can read further more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)